# My phone is soft-bricked after ADB update

Tags: adb, updates, recovery-mode, boot-loop

This is the problem:

I always connect my phone to computer, to charge it, but I tried to execute ADB shell into recovery mode.

1- I've entered into recovery mode
2- I tried to go to "Apply update from ADB"
3- I tried to execute commands from computer (but it not worked)
4- I removed the battery to force shutdown
5- I got a soft-brick (I suppose that reason is because I interrupted the update)

**EDIT**: My phone is not rooted and I didn't try to install custom roms.

I don't understand how can this cause soft-brick?
Apply update from ADB and force shutdown.

**EDIT**: I tried to wipe data and cache, it not worked for me.

**EDIT**: My phone system state is Official

Comment: What is the current state? Can you not turn on the device *or* boot into Android OS? If can't boot, is the process appears to stuck on OEM's logo or on boot animation?

Comment: When I turn on, it's stuck at Samsung logo

Answer (score 0):

Which phone is it? You have to download stock firmware for it and flash it via flashtool, adb or fastboot (depends on phone). If you have Samsung phone, then download firmware and Odin from sammobile.com and flash.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this one thing, flash/install CWM recovery using Odin or other flashing method suitable for your device. From there,  it will cakewalk to install any custom rom on your device.

Comment: Flashing CWM will void warranty, and there's not stock firmware that matches with my PDA (AP) or CSC

Comment: @codigos what is your device name? And about the warranty, each method which acquires root access will void your warranty on most android devices.

Comment: Also,  applying ADB update from PC,  requires USB debugging on your device to be switched on.

Answer (score 0):

Updating from adb is unreliable on a lot of PCs.

A much more reliable method to update (or in this case recover) your phone is to choose Apply update from external storage.

- Obtain an sd card, and format it to FAT if not already.
- Copy the official 'stock' update to the root directory of the card.
- Power off phone and insert card
- Reboot into recovery but holding volume up, home and power keys at the same time
- Apply update from external storage.
- Wipe cache partition
- Wipe data/factory reset
- Reboot system now
- Wait at least 10 minutes for the OS to load before pulling the battery or powering off the phone... It can take a long time to rebuild the caches on some models!

Of course the Recovery menu options can vary a lot between devices. And unfortunately some of the most recent phones do not have an sd card, in which cases this is not a valid answer... But you have not specified your model!